# Why EN and Not S?

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english, standard-german

I'm really confused. I cannot understand when I should use the (S) and the (EN). Here is an example :

- Nas**en**loch
- Arbeit**s**los
- Hoffnung**s**los

Why in the first word We Use EN (Nachenloch) and not S (Nachsloch)?

And why Arbeit**s**los and not Arbeit**en**los

When should I put EN or S?

Comment: It is not “Nachenloch”.  I could have corrected that, but what should I have done with “Nachsloch” then?

Comment: Because the consonant cluster -chs- is pronounced the same as -cks- in German. See *Fuchs, Luchs, Dachs.*

Comment: This question seems uncorrectable! It is perfectly clear what the question is asking for, but without the questioner thinking it through and revising it thoroughly again, I would refuse to answer it.

Comment: @Janka: Not always, especially not when the *chs* results from appending some inflection or similar adaptation to a word that originally ended on *ch* - Die Titelseite des Buchs, die Tür des Gemachs, geruchsbasiert usw.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper *geruchsbasiert* is the only in your collection with a joint element. That's was the point for me when I decided to give up: The OP didn't even take the patience to discover that it's *Nase* + *Loch*. And if you try to correct this question you get the answer. That means to me that **this is a really bad question**.

Comment: @Wolf: I think the question might have merit, but I do indeed fail to understand how the OP arrives at "Nachenloch" in the first place. However, in my comment, I specifically addressed Janka's reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

In the word "arbeit-**s**-los", a [linking](https://blogs.transparent.com/german/compound-words-das-fugen-s-im-deutschen-the-linking-s-in-german-part-1/) "s" is used to combine both parts of the word.

As copied from the articel:
The linking "s" is used when the first word of the compounding ends with one of the following syllables: -tum, -ling, -ion, -tät, -heit, -keit, -schaft, -sicht, and -ung.

For the case of "Arbeit", it is handled like "-heit" or "-keit", although it is not in the examples.

You can find more examples, where you have to use the linking "s" and where you should follow other rules.

Unfortunatly, the word "Nasenloch" (nostril) is an exception for this rule.
Have a look at the [The Oxford Guide to Middle High German](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=erGZDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA211&lpg=PA211&dq=nasenloch+fugen+s&source=bl&ots=4SrO9wK0q7&sig=ACfU3U2KbCjDAl_KQi917Z8TPgOJqx87sg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj46qCKid3pAhUQ8HMBHdUaBuMQ6AEwA3oECAgQAQ#v=snippet&q=nasenloch%20&f=false) (MHG)

[image]

Comment: There is more than one joint element for compound words because German nouns have so many different beginnings and endings. I hope this helps to improve your answer: [Overview of German joint elements](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut#%C3%9Cbersicht_deutscher_Fugenelemente) (German)

Comment: Another interesting resource with distribution data: [Fugenbildung bei zusammengesetzten Wörtern (Komposita) - Graf Ortho](http://www.rechtschreib-werkstatt.de/GrafOrtho/WZ/html/g-fugen.html)